# add exif data and comments field to fancybox jquery popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Does anyone have an idea of how to add exif data and a comments field to the fancybox popup

Adding in the *jQuery.exif* was easy..but HOW to show it in the popup is the problem?

```
   $("a.your_image_class").fancybox({
                 'title':|'Taken with a ' + $(this).exif("Make") + ' '
   + $(this).exif("Model") + ' on ' + $
   (this).exif("DateTimeOriginal"|)
   comma if last attribute
         }); | alert( + ));
```

CAN SOMEONE HELP?
thank you
Melanie

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or maybe give some markup also! BTW you need on the images  to set exif=”true” have you done it? Also there is a | which i think is wrong

Comment: also you could cache $(this).exif("Make") etc to variables and try to see if they return any value or NaN with console.log

Comment: And one last thing, are you sure the image has EXIF info in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancybox v2.x you could use the `beforeShow` callback to set the `title` BUT targeting the `.fancybox-image` *selector* (the actual image in fancybox) like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow : function () {
        this.title = 'Taken with a ' + $(".fancybox-image").exif("Make") +
            ' ' + $(".fancybox-image").exif("Model") +
            ' on ' + $(".fancybox-image").exif("DateTimeOriginal");
    }
});
```

**Note**: not tested, but if you say you already make the *jQuery.exif* plugin work, then you shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: thank you - its working! - now i just need to add a comments field, where you can comment and comments are stored, at the moment all i can manage is a comments popup, a onclick - but you can only comment not see comments
thank you
melanie